He actualizado una extensión de jupyter en visual studio code para mac y ya no puedo abrirlo
Uso visual studio code para trabajar con python y al actualizar una extensión relacionada con jupyter, no puedo volver a abrir el programa en mac. He probado a desinstalarlo y volver a instalar y me pasa lo mismo, aparece "botando" en el dock un segundo y desaparece. He reiniciado el mac y pasa exactamente lo mismo. Me han comentado varios comandos para borrar extensiones y al abrir el terminal y ejecutarlos no parece que haga absolutamente nada.¿Os ha pasado esto?

Al intentar abrir visual studio code ahora me sale este error, no sé si es algo representativo


Y borraste la extension??? borrar el programa no siempre borra las extensiones...

Buenas tardes, gracias por tu comentario :D Cómo podría borrar la extensión si no puedo abrir el programa? Un saludo y muchas gracias

La extension es un archivo en una carpeta..  no se si todas las instalaciones son iguales, pero hay una carpeta extensions que las tiene todas...

si la hay, no sé cómo encontrarla :(

Para eliminar todas las extensiones tienes que abrir la terminal y ejecutar el siguiente comando:
rm -rf ~/.vscode/extensions

Si quieres verificar la carpeta antes de eliminar, puedes hacer cd para entrar y luego un ls para ver las extensiones.

Mientras que para una instalación limpia (después de desinstalar) tendrías que ejecutar lo siguiente como indica en acá How to completely uninstall VS Code on mac?
rm -rf ~/.vscode*


Buenos días René, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Para ejecutar el comando basta con abrir el terminar, copiarlo y darle al enter verdad? Un saludo!

He probado a ejecutar ese comando y no parece hacer nada, sigue la situación igual. :(

y lo estas ejecutando donde corresponde?? estas en la carpeta donde instalaste vscode??? @AlvaroGarciaLinares

no estoy entendiendo a qué te refieres @gbianchi. Lo he ejecutado abriendo el terminal en el escritorio y pegando el comando y dándole a enter

@AlvaroGarciaLinares tenes que buscar la carpeta donde esta instalado vs code... y borrar esa carpeta.. que parte de eso, no sabes hacer?

@gbiachi la carpeta se borra al desinstalar el programa si no me equivoco. Al haber desinstalado y volver a instalarlo esa carpeta se ha borrado y creado de nuevo vacía. Si el problema estuviese ahí, digo yo que se habría solucionado. No crees?

No siempre se borran, tienes que purgarlas. En Windows tienes que hacerlo si o si, la extensión que hace el tema “transparente” VS Code daño mi instalación y tuve que borrar carpetas residuales manualmente, en Mac no he tenido problema pero es muy probable que sea igual.

@AlvaroGarciaLinares agregué un ejemplo de como verificar la carpeta, no debería de mostrar nada. Tendría que reiniciar VS Code limpio, si no toca desinstalar, borrar la carpeta y reinstalar para asegurarte de que este limpio.

Buenos días @René , he intentado lo que dices y sigo en las mismas. Abro el terminal, copio la línea de código y al darle al enter no parece que haga absolutamente nada, eso es normal? o tengo que darle a otra tecla que no sea enter? He intentado añadir una captura a la respuesta pero creo que no me deja añadir imágenes aquí. así que voy a editar la pregunta

No tiene que regresar nada si estás borrando la carpeta de extensiones, el último comando que pusiste borro todo, tienes que desinstalar y volver a instalar.

@René Por ahora nada, me sale el error que he dejado arriba adjunto pero no tengo ni idea de qué significa. Si instalo de nuevo, me sigue pasando lo mismo.
